# CSS positioning to fill container: width vs. left/right?

Tags: css, cross-browser, width, css-position

Considering:

- For elements that are absolutely positioned inside a relatively
  positioned container.
- If you want the element to fill the width of the container.
- The element is also bottom-aligned.

[image]

Is it best for maximum browser compatibility to [set a `width` in pixels](http://jsbin.com/ozaziy/1/edit) for the element, or simply [use `left` and `right`](http://jsbin.com/ozaziy/4/edit)?

Any common bugs to watch out for with either method?

Clearly, using `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` would make the code more manageable in cases where the image's width or padding were to change, but are there any downsides where `width: 300px` would be favorable instead?

Comment: Using `left: 0` and `right: 0` will work in every browser, except IE6 (and IE7 without the correct doctype). I'd say go with `left` and `right`, since it's easier to maintain the code in the long run (for example changing the size of the container).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about IE6 support anymore...

Comment: A lot of people still are forced to use IE6 at work, so it really depends on the implementation and target audience

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Historically we learnt to use `width` instead of `left & right` because IE6 didn't support
at the same time the two properties of the same axis

```
<div style="top:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;">modern browsers</div>

<div style="top:0;height:100%;position:absolute;">MSIE6</div>

<div style="left:0;right:0;position:absolute;">modern browsers</div>

<div style="left:0;width:100%;position:absolute;">MSIE6</div>

<div style="left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;">modern browsers</div>

<div style="left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;">MSIE6</div>
```

Also, this technique will not work on some elements ([including on modern browsers, by spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width) )

```
<!-- these will not work -->
<!-- edit: on some browsers they may work,
but it's not standard, so don't rely on this -->

<iframe src="" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;"></iframe>

<textarea style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;"></textarea>

<input type="text" style="position:absolute;left:0;right:0;">

<button ... ></button>

and possibly others... (some of these can't even be display:block)
```

---

But, analysing what happens in the normal static flow using the `width:auto` property

```
<div style="width:auto;padding:20px;margin:20px;background:lime;">a</div>
```

You will see it's very similar to...

```
<div style="width:auto;padding:20px;margin:20px;background:lime;
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;">b</div>
```

... same properties with the same values! This is really nice! Otherwise it will look like:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
    <div style="padding:20px;margin:20px;
        background:lime;">c</div>
</div>
```

Which is also different, because the inner div doesn't fill the y axis.
To fix this we will need css `calc()` or `box-sizing` and an unnecessary headache.

---

My answer is, `left + right | top + bottom` are really cool since they are closest to the static positioning's `width:auto`
and there is no reason to not use them. They are way easier to use compared to the alternative and they
provide much more functionality (for example, using `margin-left`, `padding-left` and `left` at the same time in
one single element).

`left + right | top + bottom` is considerably
better supported by browsers compared to the alternative `width:100% + box-sizing | calc()`
and it's also easier to use!

Of course if you don't need (as in your example) to grow the element also in the y axis, 
`width:100%` using some nested element for the padding, it's the only solution to archive support also for MSIE6

So, depends by your needs. If you want to support MSIE6 (it's the only actual reason to do that) you should use `with:100%`, otherwise use `left + right`!

Hoping to be helpful.

Comment: Would you mind explaining which part of the spec you linked to provides information about these elements that will not fill out the parent with only absolute coordinates specified? I had trouble understanding how the linked sentences lead to your list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are fine, but if you want your design to be responsive or mobile phone compatible - I would recommend using `Left:` and `Bottom:` if the container is not enclosed in `<div>`.

If it is enclosed in a `<div>` then doing it with `width: 100%` or`max-width: 200px` is a way in my opinion that causes least display problems.

Avoid using fixed widths in CSS if you want your theme to be responsive.

Comment: In this case, it isn't for a responsive design (see demos)

Answer (score -1):

Both of the solution is working in every browser without any problems. In these cases I like to add a **width: 100%; left: 0; bottom: 0;** for the element, but if you like **left:0;right:0; bottom:0;** more, than you can use that, too.

Comment: Specifying `width: 100%` without a box-sizing method would cause the element to become increased in size when a padding is applied.

Comment: I think that was not the part of the question

Comment: *Clearly, using left: 0; and right: 0; would make the code more manageable in cases where the image's width **or padding** were to change*

Comment: @Seer, are you sure about "every browser"? I should have maybe made it clearer: all major browser releases, to which [BenM's suggestion disagrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972192/css-positioning-to-fill-container-width-vs-left-right/15972598?noredirect=1#comment22766609_15972192)

Comment: @Baumr, that's right, _all major browser_ is more correct than _every browser_. But I think this is only a 'logic-chopper' thing, _every browser_ should mean _every browser in which a developer needs to check the site_. And this doesn't include IE6, nor IE7.

Comment: @Seer, I don't want to go into the debate, but you can't categorically discount IE6/7 — it depends on each individual website's traffic

Comment: @Baumr, correct. Everybody can decide if is it worth to work more, or a lot more when the usage of IE6 is 0.2% and IE7 is 0.8%. And I think the half of these numbers are only developers, who checks the sites in old browsers to see if it is working or not :) Anyway, I think we are a little bit off topic. And I agree with you what you wrote above in your comment for Khanh To.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this on all browsers (and modes) but for the IE quirks mode (e.g. in an .HTA without !DOCTYPE defined), I have created a subroutine that corrects the WIDTH or HEIGHT on elements where the LEFT/RIGHT style or the TOP/BOTTOM style are set (not “auto”). To avoid going in to all kind of unit conversions, the routine temporary removes the LEFT (or TOP) style and sets the WIDTH (or HEIGHT) to 100% to determine the RIGHT (or BOTTOM) offset in pixels.

The script is written in VBScript, but it should be do difficult to translate the idea to JavaScript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="VBScript">

Option Explicit

Sub Justify(ByVal hElement)

    Dim sStyleTop, iTop, iBottom, sStyleLeft, iLeft, iRight

    With hElement
        If .currentStyle.top <> "auto" And .currentStyle.height = "auto" And .currentStyle.bottom <> "auto" Then
            iTop = .offsetTop
            sStyleTop = .currentStyle.top
            .style.top = "auto"
            .style.height = "100%"
            iBottom = -.offsetTop 
            .style.height = .offsetHeight - iTop - iBottom & "px"
            .style.top = sStyleTop
        End If
        If .currentStyle.left <> "auto" And .currentStyle.width = "auto" And .currentStyle.right <> "auto" Then
            iLeft = .offsetLeft
            sStyleLeft = .currentStyle.left
            .style.left = "auto"
            .style.width = "100%"
            iRight = -.offsetLeft 
            .style.width = .offsetWidth - iLeft - iRight & "px"
            .style.left = sStyleLeft
        End If
        For Each hElement In .Children
            Justify hElement
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub window_onload

    Justify Document.body

End Sub

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #outer{
        background:blue;
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        right:20px;
        bottom:30px;
        left:40px;
    }
    #inner{
        background:green;
        position:absolute;
        top:40px;
        right:30px;
        bottom:20px;
        left:10px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The command to justify all elements in a document is:

```
Justify Document.body
```

I am invoking this from the onload event as it concerns a fixed size .HTA in my case but I expect the routine also to work on the onsize event for sizable windows (or parent elements).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you mistakenly post your answer on the wrong question?

Comment: Why?, I think this answers the expectation that when you predefine the left and the right (or top and bottom) with CSS, the width  (or height) should be calculated by the browser.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but please [refer to my questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15972192/1779823) and [SO guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) — hope that helps?

Comment: It indirectly answeres "_are there any downsides where width: 300px would be favorable instead?_": Yes, where you can't predict the width of the Window or parent element and want to have both left and right 'fixed' aligned. It is actually an answere for situations where you "_would make the code more manageable_".

Comment: Please refer to the SO guidelines, answers should address questions directly. Also, for the record, adding VBScript or JavaScript to achieve a simple layout is excessive for this CSS question. I wouldn't say it makes code more manageable; though I appreciate you trying — thank you