# Make a button fill the full width of container element?

Tags: css

I'm converting from using `div`'s as buttons to actual buttons, and now I need to make buttons fill the full width of the container.

[image]

Code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="button">
    Fills the full width
  </div>

  <button class="button">
    Does not fill the full width
  </button>

</div>
```

Adding `display:block` to `.button` does not work (although I'm sure that has got to be part of at the answer?), and neither does `left: 0; right: 0`. `width: 100%` sort of works, but it ignores the container's padding property and makes the button go too close to the right side of the container.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mn40mz2n/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add the "box-sizing: border-box" property to all elements. The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This will ensure your measurements across elements are correct and take into account the padding. display: block and width: 100% is the correct way to go full width but you need to remove the left/right margin on the button as it pushes it outside the containing element.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
} 

.container {
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.button {
    background-color: #bbb;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

for more information on the box-sizing property, read the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: This solved the issue for me on Anki after a long period of suffering with different decks.

Answer (score 22):

It doesn't need to be too complicated.  Boil it down to what you want it to do first, and then add padding, etc afterward.  For your button just do this, and it will stretch to the entire width.

```
.button {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Possible answers:

[Answer 1: Why does display:block not stretch buttons or input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584890/why-does-displayblock-not-stretch-buttons-or-input-elements)

[Answer 2: CSS positioning to fill container: width vs. left/right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972192/css-positioning-to-fill-container-width-vs-left-right)

```
width: 100%
```

is working properly. The button moves towards right because of the `left-margin` in the button.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [CSS3 calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

If you need this to work on legacy browsers, see the acceptance [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}

button.button {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="button">
    Fills the full width
  </div>

  <button class="button">
    Does not fill the full width
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: This is totally awesome and new to me. Pretty sure `box-sizing: border-box` is more what I was thinking of, but maybe this is a better way to go? Certainly the unsupported browsers are not a concern.

Comment: Yes, CSS3 calc() is awesome. I wanted to change the minimum of your original markup, but worth saying that I would try to use @JoshuaKelly's approach, as it's simpler and "the simpler, the better".