# How can I make button auto width to its parent div

Tags: html, css

I can't make a button auto its width to the parent div it is a child of. How do I make that?

[image: See the problem in action].

Here is the code (html structure) if you need it:

```html
<div class="drp">
  <button class="drp-btn" id="i-drp-btn">m/s</button>
  <div id="i-speed-drp" class="drp-content">
    <button class="drp-btn-elem" value="m/s">m/s</button>
    <button class="drp-btn-elem" value="km/h">km/h</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS to the demo I created. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Also take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a button fill the full width of container element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558184/make-a-button-fill-the-full-width-of-container-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `width: 100%` on your button style?
It should take the size of the parent, except if you have `margin` defined on your parent or `padding` defined on your button.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you so much! I am so dumb, sry, just got into html/css.

Comment: Don't worry, we all started somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to make all buttons of that class use 100% of the width, then you should add that in the CSS code by adding this line:

```
.drp-btn-elem{width: 100%}
```

Here's a snipet:

```css
.drp-btn-elem{width: 100%}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="drp">
    <button class="drp-btn" id="i-drp-btn">m/s</button>
    <div id="i-speed-drp" class="drp-content">
        <button class="drp-btn-elem" value="m/s">m/s</button>
        <button class="drp-btn-elem" value="km/h">km/h</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button width full width of parent div, you can add width: 100% for button

Comment: Please ask for clarification with a comment, not in your answer.